# FirebaseCrashlytics: Error handling uncaught exception & java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, crashlytics, android-r8

I am getting this error message, which seems to be in relation with R8 minifying. It works with the debug build with minify enabled, which is weird. But I am getting it definitely in the release build type and when downloading the app from the Play Store. Also when building on the CI, so cache or something like that cannot really be a problem, it worked before.

```
2021-03-30 14:51:56.495 11289-11289/? E/FirebaseCrashlytics: Error handling uncaught exception
    java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at planner.n63.a(Utils.java:13)
        at planner.v00.a(CrashlyticsController.java:10)
        at planner.y10.uncaughtException(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:4)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1073)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1068)
        at java.lang.Thread.dispatchUncaughtException(Thread.java:2203)
```

```
// build.gradle :project
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath Libs.Google.gmsGoogleServices
        classpath Libs.Google.Firebase.crashlyticsGradlePlugin
    }
}
```

```
// build.gradle :app
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        ...
        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            minifyEnabled true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...
    implementation platform(Libs.Google.Firebase.bom)
    implementation Libs.Google.Firebase.analytics
    implementation Libs.Google.Firebase.crashlytics
}

// Must be applied after dependencies
if (file("google-services.json").exists()) {
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
}
```

```kotlin
class App : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to be solved by using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60310973/10319730

Comment: are you sure the accepted answer will solve the problem?

Comment: I got this error only when I simulated low internet connectivity. but why!

Answer (score 0):

Low Internet connectivity (bad internet)
this occurs if the device doesn't have a good internet connection.
that is what happened in my case. try to simulate bad internet on your emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I have a some problem.
In my case I have many buildFlavors and buildVariants. I think Android Stuido cache my old project structure and all google-services.json files not put into apk. Clean project help me.

You can see Logs with "FirebaseCrashlytics" key and find out real firebase project who chained with uor